# Why javascript will not run in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

This page can run perfectly as i think in Safari, some glitches on Chrome, but totally no effect on firefox, why?

Comment: Tell us what we are expecting to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script uses the `innerText` property:

```
document.getElementById("todae").innerText = "is " + weekday[myTodae.getDay()];
document.getElementById("myTitle").innerText = weekday[myTodae.getDay()] + " es " + weekday[myTodae.getDay()] +" | "+ weekday[myTodae.getDay()] + " go! ";
```

Firefox doesn't support `innerText` (it uses `textContent`), you could use `innerHTML` instead. However, since you're including jQuery you can also use:

```
current_weekday = weekday[myTodae.getDay()];
$("#todae").text("is " + current_weekday);
$("#myTitle").text(current_weekday + " es " + current_weekday +" | "+ current_weekday + " go! ");
```